# WPF DatePicker - write custom datetime format

Tags: wpf, datepicker

i have in my application DatePicker. I would like write standart DateTime format (e.g. 2016-10-18), select DateTime from calendar or write custom format (e.g. ddmmrrrr, ddmm, ddmmrr...) 
I made DateTimeConverter:

```
class DateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime emptyDateTime;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out emptyDateTime) && emptyDateTime == DateTime.MinValue)
            return DateTime.Now;
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int valueNumber;
        string valueStr = value.ToString().Replace(".", "");
        if (!int.TryParse(valueStr, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out valueNumber))
            return DateTime.Now;
        if (valueStr.Length == 8) //format ddmmrrrr
        {
            DateTime emptyDateTime;
            //for removing empty datetime (01.01.0001)
            return DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out emptyDateTime) && emptyDateTime == DateTime.MinValue
                ? (object) null
                : new DateTime(valueNumber%10000, (valueNumber/10000)%100, valueNumber/1000000);
        }
        if (valueStr.Length == 6) //format ddmmrr
            return new DateTime(2000 + valueNumber % 100, (valueNumber / 100) % 100, valueNumber / 10000);
        if (valueStr.Length == 4) //format ddmm
            return new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, valueNumber % 100, valueNumber / 100);
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

And this is my DatePicker:

```
<DatePicker Focusable="True" Grid.Column="4"
                            Text="{Binding Order.DateTime, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeConverter}}" 
                            PreviewKeyDown="DatePicker_OnPreviewKeyDown"/>
```

This is property for binding:

```
class Order{
  public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

My problems are:
When DatePicker is null, value in Order.DateTime is 01.01.0001
When I write my format (ddmmrrrr), value in Order.DateTime is DateTime.Now

I dont see whats wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `Converter` checks the `TryParse` wrong. Change it to:

```
 if (!DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out emptyDateTime) || emptyDateTime == DateTime.MinValue)
        return DateTime.Now;

 return value;
```

Comment: Sounds right, but you should also change the && to ||. When either the string could not be parsed or it could be parsed but was DateTime.MinValue it should return DateTime.Now

Comment: Thanks, it looks good, but initial value is 01.01.0001 because if body in your example not return DateTime.Now but return value.

Comment: I would like default value in datepicker is DateTime.Now

Comment: @blueray: sorry I can't get your problem right now. The only thing I see is that the ConvertBack has the same incorrect check at `return DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out emptyDateTime) && emptyDateTime == DateTime.MinValue`. When I simply try  `DateTime test;  if (!DateTime.TryParse(null, out test) || test == DateTime.MinValue) test = DateTime.Now;        MessageBox.Show(test.ToString());` (test with value=null at converter) it shows me `DateTime.Now`... Maybe ConvertBack is the problem or I didn't got the question correct.

Comment: Ok, your answer is good, but problem is probably elsewhere. In DatePicker i see today date, but send 01.01.0001, probably value not binding. i must choose manualy value from calendar or write my format and then is correct

Comment: I need datepicker call Order.DateTime setter after start application because datepicker call only Order.DateTime and this is empty after start.